# how to send Message between two android applications using RabbitMQ

Tags: android, rabbitmq

I have created an application in Android for RabbitMQ using RabbitMQ-Android tutorial. It is working fine. Now I want to create two applications in Android and I want to make a communication between them using RabbitMQ.

I have not found any example nor tutorial regarding this issue.
It would be a great help, if you could provide a link with code.

---

Thanks for your reply. I have created my first application using this tutorial only. But this tutorial shows the connection between Android and .NET application through RabbitMQ. I don't have .NET application. So, I want to create one more application in Android, and I want to send message between these two applications using RabbitMQ.

Is it possible??
Please give me any suggestion on this topic.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simon Dixon has a good tutorial that should get you going: http://simonwdixon.wordpress.com/2011/06/03/getting-started-with-rabbitmq-on-android-part-1/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have created my first application using this tutorial only. But this tutorial shows the connection between android and .net application through rabbitmq. I don't have .net application. So I want to create one more application in android, and want to send message between these two applications using rabbitMQ. Is it possible?? Please give me any suggestion in this regard. Thanks Manisha

Comment: Look at "Publishing messages" in this tutorial: http://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Python script below to send message to Android client application.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika
import time

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
    host='localhost'))

channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

i = 0

while True:

  channel.basic_publish(exchange='logs',
                      routing_key='hello',
                      body='Hello World, ' + str(i))
  print " [x] Sent 'Hello World!'" + str(i)
  i += 1
  time.sleep(1)
connection.close()
```